# Why are most of my convolutional network's filters barely/not changing?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I've been training a convolutional network for image classification using the CIFAR-10 data set. Its architecture is as follows:

1. InputLayer (32x32x3 neurons, 0 parameters)
2. ConvolutionalLayer (28x28x64 neurons, 5x5x3x64 kernel, rectified_linear, 4864 parameters)
3. MaxPoolingLayer (14x14x64 neurons, 2x2x1 pooling window, 0 parameters)
4. FullyConnectedLayer (64 neurons, rectified_linear, 802880 parameters)
5. FullyConnectedLayer (10 neurons, sigmoid, 650 parameters)

It works reasonably well for quite a simple network, but when I look at the 64 filters it's producing, most of them seem to have either not changed or hardly changed from their initial values.

Initial:

[image: Epoch 0]

Final:

[image: Epoch 21]

(On the left, every filter has had its colour values normalised to the range of values across all filters. On the right, they have each been normalised only to the range of values in their own filters.)

As can be seen, only a few of the filters change significantly - most change only very slightly, and some don't even seem to change at all. This makes me think that there's something wrong either with my network design or my implementation. I figure that if most of the filters are making a negligible contribution, I'm probably using a lot more processing power than I need to.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be causing this?